# Enemy ignore others layer with raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D game. I need the enemy to be able to spot the player and shoot, I did it with Physics2d.Raycast, but if there is another layer in front of the enemy, it still detects the player and shoots, although the damage is not passed through the other layer to the player, but the render line I made still shoots and hits the obstacle. I need the enemy to be unable to see through the other layer. If the code is needed, I provide it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select the layer for working on,

```
int layer_mask = LayerMask.GetMask("Enemy");

if (Physics2d.Raycast (ray, out hit, distance, layer_mask)) 
{
   //You can do your calculation specifically in this layer
}
```

Comment: I did it but enemy still ignore others layer. I make physics2d.raycast(vector2.position, vector.right, 100f , PlayerLayer) doesn't help me. I think I need another type of raycast2d on docs unity I didn't understand examples

Comment: Enemy shoot the raycast ro the player and raycast ignore obstacle with another layer

Comment: Now enemy shoot trought other layers with colliders and deals damage